# jsf - entity framework for caching remotely received objects - same references

Tags: entity-framework, jsf, caching, ejb

I am programming an jsf admin panel for a 3-tier architecture to administrate database values. There are multiple tables with multiple relationships.

All Entity-Objects are received remotely from stateless EJB session beans in an EAR using Hibernate.

Quickly I had multiple instances of same Entitie-Objects (rows) in my code since the same objects are received multiple times remotely.

Now I thought about creating something like a ServiceLocator for those Entitie-Objects at session or application scope level so that each Entity is only once in the system and everytime a Entity gets received it is replaced with the cached reference and its properties are updated to the new ones.

Since all Entity informations are already saved in Hibernate xml or annotations it would be best to use them to provide that service.

So what I want is something like that takes care of caching and unique references but should be between the application- and web-tier since the app-tier is stateless to provide high scalability.

Comment: isnt it better to cache on the layer of hibernate ? like http://code.google.com/p/hibernate-memcached/ ? without involving the jsf... ?

Comment: Hibernate is used on the stateless application level, not the web-tier.